# Spring jpa data jpa composite with 3 primary key using IdClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, relationship

I have many to many relation between user and comment. It works but in a way that the user can only make one comment. I need to add another generated id that makes the key unique.

**The Comment Class**

```
 @Entity
@IdClass(CommentPK.class)
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private Long id;


    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gameID" ,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Game game;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    private String Text;

    public Comment() {
        super();
        this.id = null;
        this.game = null;
        this.user = null;
        Text = null;
    }
    public Comment(Game game, User user, String text) {
        this();
        this.id = null;
        this.game = game;
        this.user = user;
        Text = text;
    }
    public Comment(Game game, String text) {
        this();
        this.id = null;
        this.game = game;
        this.Text = text;
    } }//setters and getters
```

**The CommentPK**

```
public class CommentPK implements Serializable {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long game;

    private Long user; }//setters and getters
```

**The Error not all of it is really big**

```
Can not set java.lang.Long field guru.springframework.domain.CommentPK.game to guru.springframework.domain.TF_Game
```

It was working fine without the generated id.

Comment: Why? Why are you making your life complex like that? Why don't you use a single-column, purely technical, autogenerated primary key for your entity?

Comment: i need to get the comment for game and also can get the user comment ? also when the game got deleted it's comments got deleted too

Comment: That is not a reason to put the user and the game in the **ID** of the entity. Make them part of the entity, not of its ID.

Comment: it works i removed the commentPK and also remove the @Id annotation from the user and game it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code the error message states that types are not matching between idClass and entity.

as you see your idclass has Long,Long,Long as types, whereas your entity has Long, Game, User.
perhaps try the following

```
 @Entity
 @IdClass(CommentPK.class)
 public class Comment {
@Id
private Long id;

@Id
@Column(name="gameID")
private Long gameId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "gameID" ,referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Game game;

@Id
@Column(name="userID")
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;

private String Text;
```

and rename the fields in IdClass according to the properties in the entity.